# 2019 Honda HRV Monitor Catalyst, EVAP, 02, EGR saying "not ready"

Tags: honda, troubleshooting, inspection, hrv

My 2019 Honda HR-V recently had a dead battery.

I need to take it for a NY state inspection but it is failing saying:

- Monitor Catalyst-not ready
- Monitor EVAP-not ready
- Monitor 02-not ready
- Monitor EGR-not ready

I understand I need to drive it to get it ready, but I have driven it 70 miles on the highway and 30+ miles locally and it still is not ready.

Is there something I can do to get it ready? Is there a possibility of something significant being an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just driving the vehicle will sometimes NOT get you where you need to be. What you need to complete is a *drive cycle*. A drive cycle is a specific set of driving conditions which need to be met. Here are instructions for the a Honda drive cycle (source: https://antiochstarsmogcheck.com/honda-acura-drive-cycle/):

> **Drive Cycle Prerequisites**

> The gas tank should be between 1/4 and 3/4 full with the vehicle having been stopped with the motor off for 6 hours or more. Ensure the air temperature is between 40° and 95°F.

> **Drive Cycle for the Honda/Acura Vehicle**

> 1. Start the motor and keep the car idle for 20 seconds. Don’t touch the accelerator.
> 2. Rev the engine to 2000 RPM for 3 minutes. The temperature should be at 1/3 of the scale or higher.
> 3. Idle for 20 seconds again.
> 4. Go to a highway and drive between 50-60mph for 20 minutes. You should be in D or 5th gear. Don’t utilize cruise control. At some point in the journey, coast for 90 seconds (take your foot off the accelerator).
> 5. Conduct city driving for 10 minutes, and during this time, perform some coasting.
> 6. Once completed, let the vehicle turn off and sit for 30 minutes with the engine off.